# Assigning a Ruby variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I spent the last couple of hours on this little mystery.

I am passing to my (Rails) view a variable called `type` that has one of these values:

```
- us
- uk
- fr
- es
- it
- ...
```

and in ruby, I am creating an identifier from it that will be used further in JS, so:

```
<% country_company_name = "#{type}_company_name" %>
```

and then I pass it to JS, so the code looks like this:

```
<% country_company_name = "#{type}_company_name" %>
<script>
    $("#<%= country_company_name %>").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
```

The code above generates this:

```
$("#uk_company_name")...
```

Looks good - exactly what I need; however, JS doesn't "accept" this code and the autocomplete doesn't work.

However, if I skip the value composition in ruby and just write this:

```
<% country_company_name = "uk_company_name" %>
    <script>
        $("#<%= country_company_name %>").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
```

then JS accepts the code and everything works smoothly.

I am pulling my hair and cannot find out why the value from the ruby variable is not accepted in JS as an identification.

**EDIT:** Adding an image of how the identifier is rendered in the DOM (all looks good):
[image]

Comment: What does the rendered code look like when you see the source code? If it does indeed show `$("#uk_company_name")` it should work... could something be wrong with your JS?

Comment: The JS is interpreted by the browser, so it shouldn't know the difference between both your examples... the output should be the same.

Comment: It renders exactly this: `$("#uk_company_name")`, but form some reason, JS doesn't accept it.

Comment: The JS is unaware of how that string got there... whether you typed it manually, parsed it from a var directly, or used the concatenation method, it should all produce the same result. Are you sure that there's not something else going on? Maybe turbolinks is the issue? Did you try enclosing the JS it in some kind of on document ready block? Did you check your JS console for errors?

Comment: @user984621 any console errors ?

Comment: Save the generated HTML from the working version and the broken version to disk and _diff_ the two files. There's probably a (maybe subtle) difference.

Comment: No console errors. @Stefan - will try that.

Comment: What do you mean javascript doesn't "accept" the code? Have you tried putting a JS debugger breakpoint there and make sure it is hit? I wonder if it has to do with turbolinks not re-runnning your JS